# Wireless xbox 360 controller for PC never shuts off if disconnected

Tags: xbox-360, controllers

So I'm done playing and I shut off my pc, the controller starts blinking and never stops. Ever. I have to remove the battery pack if I want it to stop. Is there another way? Any way to get it to stop trying to connect to something after a given time?

Comment: Does the controller disconnect after 15 minutes while the PC is still one? This used to work for me with this exact setup.

Comment: yeah, but I usually turn it off right after I'm done playing

Comment: I'm afraid there is no other way than to remove the battery pack. I had this issue myself too. Either wait 15 minutes after using the controller or remove the battery pack.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for you.
Is your PC Windows 10?
If it is win10, install the Xbox program, with the program installed, click on the central button of the controller, all the menu settings and the controller settings will appear, in the controller settings you can choose to leave the LED off, or you can do this every time you finish playing.